# How heavy in terms of performance the ReactDOM.render function at the start?

Tags: reactjs, performance, startup, react-dom

How bad it might be for performance to use multiple `ReactDOM.render` functions simultaneously? For example, up to 30+ `ReactDOM.render` calls.

I know it may sound strange. I'm currently working on a large web project that uses single `ReactDOM.render` function. One of the largest problems we've come up with was update to React 18. Since the project is pretty big and contains many legacy code there are many places where you can meet usage of legacy approaches that are not supported by the newest React version. I want to split one SPA on multiple independent subapplications (a.k.a. micro-frontends), but still use a single deployment build, have in-memory cache that can be shared across apps, keep SPA experience for users, etc. Yet, at the same time have the capability of gradual migration on a newer versions of React.

We've already managed to create a working proof of concept by refactoring two subapps. Currently the startup of every app looks somewhat like this:

```js
// Subscribe on URL path change.
observer.on('changed', () => {
  if (window.location.path.includes(targetPath)) {
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, elementContainer);
  } else {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(elementContainer);
  }
});
```

As you can see we don't start React immediately, unless we enter the specific route. But ideally I would prefer if application's entry point looked like this:

```
const AppEntryPoint = () => {
  <Switch>
    <Route path="...">
      <App />
    </Route>
    <Route>{null}</Route>
  </Switch>
};

ReactDOM.render(<AppEntryPoint />, elementContainer);
```

And the question is: how bad it may be at the startup with 30+ entry points like this? Are there any other serious issues that I didn't notice?

Answer (score 1):

Ive actually done similar to upgrade a legacy app and it was fine. I think the accumulative render time is very similar to having it in one tree.

However, I think you should think carefully before doing this. The release notes say:

> Although the changes are usually small, you’ll still have the ability to make them at your own pace. The new rendering behavior in React 18 is only enabled in the parts of your app that use new features.

It honestly could be a small number of broken components caused by state update batching. Your approach is not necessarily incorrect depending on how bad the situation is; but you should only do it if its really extreme. This will come at great cost, and also be hard to reverse. Maybe a small number of common components have a problem?

You could just wrap all your state updates in a flush and work backwards to remove them: https://blog.devgenius.io/understanding-automatic-batching-in-react-18-fb5b8fdf062d

I would usually encourage an incremental approach like yours, but you should think carefully about the cost of incremental vs big bang here because of how large the proposed changes would be with the incremental approach compared to the end state.

I'll also add, if you do do this, it might be better to add placeholder HTML elements to the pages -- then query these and load the react tree. Coupling to the URL will make moving code around harder. This worked for me in the past.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! There are some other reasons why we want to split our SPA. For example, really slow build time (it takes 2 mins for MacBook 13" to start our application locally) and most of the time developers work with one or two applications at a time.

We've being thinking about it for a long time now. We're going to integrate a new approach gradually - one application at a time and we'll see how it comes.

Comment: Would build time be fixed by splitting into multiple roots? I guess it might on CI if you have multiple agents.  If you are using webpack/rollup, consider changing. Vite uses esbuild, and the speed diff of esbuild is *huge*. Your concept BTW is very similar to the idea of "micro frontends". Have a look at https://github.com/umijs/qiankun. Also Slava Ukraini from UK! Best of luck.

Comment: Yes, it's gonna be "micro frontends". Every application has it's own repository, but currently those applications are just regular React components that get installed and imported as NPM packages to the central entry point of the whole SPA. They don't have their own webpack builds, only the central repo does, which is pretty inefficient and slow. Now we're trying to adopt Webpack Module Federation concept - every app becomes self sustained and has a separate build. The central repository won't need to build the whole SPA anymore, only a small entry point chunk.

Comment: Yep makes sense. If you're committed to microfrontends long term this changes the tradeoffs -- since you arent ever going to need to bring it back into 1 app. If you think this is right for you, you should go for it. Perf wise...I honestly wouldnt worry. I had once like 40 roots on a page and no one noticed (was a huge incremental upgrade of a legacy app).

Comment: When you do this, it could be a great time to consider esbuild rather than webpack. Your gains would be massive! And I suspect webpack is losing market share at a rapid rate to it.

Comment: Hmm... Interesting point. I'll give esBuild a try, thanks!